# Custom SAMLUserDetailsService not populating custom UserDetails

Tags: spring-security, saml-2.0, spring-saml

I have a Spring project and I'm converting my current authentication to use SAML2.

I have everything working as far as authentication, but I'm having difficulty in getting the SAML2 extension to insert my custom UserDetails object into the Spring Security Context authentication object.

I have a custom UserDetailsService, defined below:

```
public class SAMLAuthManager implements SAMLUserDetailsService {

    private static final Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(JDBCAuthManager.class);

    @Override
    public Object loadUserBySAML(SAMLCredential credential) throws UsernameNotFoundException {
        logger.info("Credential attributes: " + credential.getAttributes());
        for (int x = 0; x < credential.getAttributes().size(); x++) {
            Attribute attr = credential.getAttributes().get(x);
            List<XMLObject> attrValues = attr.getAttributeValues();
            StringBuilder strBuilder = new StringBuilder();
            for (int g = 0; g < attrValues.size(); g++) {
                XMLObject currObj = attrValues.get(g);
                strBuilder.append(currObj.toString()).append(",");
            }
            strBuilder.deleteCharAt(strBuilder.length() - 1);
            logger.info(attr.getFriendlyName() + ", " + strBuilder.toString());
        }
        String username = credential.getNameID().getValue();
            userWrapper.setStaff(s);
            logger.info("Returning wrapper: " + userWrapper);
            return userWrapper;
        } else {
            return null;
        }
    }

}
```

I have also configured this userDetails in my security context config:

```
    <bean id="samlAuthenticationProvider" class="org.springframework.security.saml.SAMLAuthenticationProvider">
        <property name="userDetails" ref="samlUserDetails" />
    </bean>
```

However, when I inspect the SecurityContextHolder, post authentication, this line:

```
SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication().getCredentials();
```

returns an object of type `org.springframework.security.saml.SAMLCredential`.

I checked to see if Spring populated the Principal with the custom object (`SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication().getPrincipal()`) but it did not, that's just a `String` with the username populated.

Any ideas?
Thanks

Comment: Ok - So I see that Spring populates `SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication().getDetails()` with the custom UserDetails object.  This is different from how other Authentication managers I have used work (for example the LDAP one). Any reason for this?

Comment: Normally I've seen Spring Security fills the SecurityContextHolder().getContext().getDetails() with an object of type `org.springframework.security.web.authentication.WebAuthenticationDetails` so it seems to me that Spring SAML extension may be doing things differently?

Answer (score 6):

The principal is by default forced to be String (in order to always permit replication of Principal which was earlier an un-serializable NameID).

This can be changed by setting `forcePrincipalAsString` in `SAMLAuthenticationProvider` to `false`, which will make Spring SAML include your object provided by `SAMLUserDetailsService` as principal in the `Authentication` object.

The result of call to `SAMLUserDetailsService` is always available under `SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication().getDetails()`.